# Node.js EventEmitter events not sharing event loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, eventemitter

Perhaps the underlying issue is how the [node-kafka](https://www.npmjs.com/package/kafka-node) module I am using has implemented things, but perhaps not, so here we go...

Using the node-kafa library, I am facing an issue with subscribing to `consumer.on('message')` events. The library is using the standard `events` module, so I think this question might be generic enough.

My actual code structure is large and complicated, so here is a pseudo-example of the basic layout to highlight my problem. (Note: This code snippet is untested so I might have errors here, but the syntax is not in question here anyway)

```
var messageCount = 0;
var queryCount = 0;

// Getting messages via some event Emitter
consumer.on('message', function(message) {
    message++;
    console.log('Message #' + message);

    // Making a database call for each message
    mysql.query('SELECT "test" AS testQuery', function(err, rows, fields) {
        queryCount++;
        console.log('Query   #' + queryCount);
    });
})
```

What I am seeing here is when I start my server, there are 100,000 or so backlogged messages that kafka will want to give me and it does so through the event emitter. So I start to get messages. To get and log all the messages takes about 15 seconds.

This is what I would expect to see for an output assuming the mysql query is reasonably fast:

```
Message #1
Message #2
Message #3
...
Message #500
Query   #1
Message #501
Message #502
Query   #2
... and so on in some intermingled fashion
```

I would expect this because my first mysql result should be ready very quickly and I would expect the result(s) to take their turn in the event loop to have the response processed. What I am actually getting is:

```
Message #1
Message #2
...
Message #100000
Query   #1
Query   #2
...
Query   #100000
```

I am getting every single message before a mysql response is able to be processed. So my question is, why? Why am I not able to get a single database result until all the message events are complete?

Another note: I set a break point at `.emit('message')` in node-kafka and at `mysql.query()` in my code and I am hitting them turn-based. So it appears that all 100,000 emits are not stacking up up front before getting into my event subscriber. So there went my first hypothesis on the problem.

Ideas and knowledge would be very appreciated :)

Comment: What happens if you increase the number of stored messages to a much larger number? Is it possible that your mysql simply is that slow?

Comment: @Avery I had wondered that, but when I replicate this with only a single message to process, I cannot even perceive the delay for the mysql response. This is all running locally too. And the actual mysql query is extremely simple (just a SELECT for ~8 fields from a single table row and that table only has about 60 rows right now)

Comment: If this example is actually representative of your code, then I'm lost as well. Can you actually produce this result with this example? I don't have a MySQL instance available to test with.

Comment: Have you configured `node-kafka` with a large enough `fetchMaxBytes` value so that all those 100K messages are transferred in one request? EventEmitter is synchronous, it doesn't use the Node event loop, so if 100K messages come in at once, they might all get emitted before your async code gets a chance to run.

Comment: @Avery I just put my above example into my actual code and ran it. I am getting the same results. After about 20 seconds the message logs complete and immediate the query logs begin.

Comment: @robertklep Thank you! So in kafka-node's examples they show the default overrides example with `fetchMaxBytes: 1024*10`. In the other default overrides they had values equal to the defaults and they even noted it, so I assumed this was the case with this property. Your question inspired me to look into their code and see its default is actually `fetchMaxBytes: 1024*1024`. So yes, I was actually taking in ALL the messages in one request. And I was not aware that EventEmitter is synchronous :)

Comment: @EricOlson I actually assumed, because of the documentation, that 10K was the default too.

Comment: @robertklep I changed the override to 1024*10 as in the documentation and got the results I had been expecting :)

Comment: @robertklep Just prodding you to post your answer as an answer :)

Comment: @JMM done. Also added a possible workaround for large number of events coming in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `node-kafka` driver uses quite a liberal buffer size (1M), which means that it will get as many messages from Kafka that will fit in the buffer. If the server is backlogged, and depending on the message size, this may mean (tens of) thousands of messages coming in with one request.

Because EventEmitter is synchronous (it doesn't use the Node event loop), this means that the driver will emit (tens of) thousands of events to its listeners, and since it's synchronous, it won't yield to the Node event loop until all messages have been delivered.

I don't think you can work around the flood of event deliveries, but I don't think that specifically the event delivery is problematic. The more likely problem is starting an asynchronous operation (in this case a MySQL query) for each event, which may flood the database with queries.

A possible workaround would be to use a queue instead of performing the queries directly from the event handlers. For instance, with [`async.queue`](https://github.com/caolan/async#queue) you can limit the number of concurrent (asynchronous) tasks. The "worker" part of the queue would perform the MySQL query, and in the event handlers you'd merely push the message onto the queue.

Comment: Thanks @robertklep. I will give the async.queue a try. I am handing my own queue so that there is only one mysql query and mem-caching the results for the waiting requests to use, but I suspect a well maintained/tested module will be better :)